# Empty array is shown as object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I wrote a utility function for my nextjs project. In there, I got something that I unexpected. I initialised an empty array which be filled with the data later. When I type check that empty array, it shows an object. I don't want an object. I want an array. Why? Could someone told me why does it happen.

strong text[image: Problem screenshoot]

Comment: In JS, arrays are objects. `Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations.` -MDN

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes typeof array is an object in javascript

if you want to check one variable is an object or array then you can use
`Array.isArray()`

```
console.log(Array.isArray(arr)) // true
console.log(Array.isArray(obj)) // false
```